# How can I modify objects inside frames with AS3 in a permanent way?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, frames, timeline

I have a MovieClip symbol created with flash in a fla file library. There is a textfield in frame one of this movieclip's timeline . There is another frame in the movieclip timeline. There is a custon class definition for this symbol. It is a flipping card in a memory game.

I access the textfield by going to frame 2 (gotoAndStop(2)) and setting the textfield's **text** property ( this.field.text = "hello" ). However if I go to frame 1 and then return to frame 2, the text becomes the original one in the library's symbol. I have to modify the **text** propery again in a showFace method I've written.

Besides, I cannot pass parameters in the  constructor because it is a symbol in the library and that would give errors.

I find this behaviour of flash extremely weird.

Is there a way I can set properties inside frames permanently?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically no. Each frame is designed to appear as it is set. Try using programatic visibilies or add/remove from stage.

Comment: Thank you shortstick, I guess I'll have to leave it the way it is now. It works but I find it kind of dirty. I thought there could be an undocumented way to do what I want.